# For some reason Files.write doesn't save the text to file from TextArea Javafx

Tags: javafx, textarea

```
Path path = Paths.get(access.getFilePath());
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);

    String originalText;

    File input = new File(access.getFilePath());
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");

    Element htmlElement = doc.select(htmlValue.get(punchLineTextField.getId())).first();
    originalText = htmlElement.toString();
    htmlElement.text(punchLineTextField.getText());

    content = content.replaceAll(originalText, htmlElement.toString());

    htmlElement = doc.select(htmlValue.get(newsDatePicker.getId())).first();
    originalText = htmlElement.toString();
    htmlElement.text(newsDatePicker.getValue().toString());

    content = content.replaceAll(originalText, htmlElement.toString());

    htmlElement = doc.select(htmlValue.get(welcomeMessageTextArea.getId())).first();
    originalText = htmlElement.toString();
    htmlElement.text(welcomeMessageTextArea.getText());

    content = content.replaceAll(originalText, htmlElement.toString());

    Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
```

The TextField and DatePicker values are saved into the file correctly (which is an HTML file).

However, TextArea text is not being saved for some reason. It grabs the original text correctly but does not save it properly. Why?

SOLUTION: replace function doesn't like new lines in text. Either remove newlines from text or use regex to remove lines while reading file.

Comment: So do you know 100% for sure that `content` actually has a value in that last line, just before its written to the fils?

Comment: Yes. It content has value of the the entire HTML document with modifications made from replaceAll function, however it does not replace TextArea text for some reason.

Comment: Alternatively,  perhaps you have read access to the given `path` but not write access? Although I would expect that would throw some sort of  exception.

Comment: As I said, it successfully edits first two html tags with content in the actual file. The problem is only with TextArea and I have absolutely 0 clue as to why.

Comment: Oh, OK. My mistake. I read that wrong.